# JQuery - How to put row's <input> value into a list

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a checkbox input on each row. I would like to put all the value  of this input (ordered) into a var list when the href="#" class="up" or the href="#" class="down" is clicked (moving a row up or down).

In summury, I want to know how call the dom element "value" of the "checkbox input" in a whole table.

table:

```
            <table>
            //first row
            <tr>
            <td><a href="/ezmapping/layer/edit/1">ra_general.shp, burton449</a></td>
            <td><label for="id_layers_0"><input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="id_layers_0" value="1" name="layers"/></label></td>
            <td><a href="/ezmapping/map/super/LayerStyle/1">Style</a></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="up"><img src="/static/main/img/arrow_up.png"></a>
                <a href="#" class="down"><img src="/static/main/img/arrow_down.png"></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            .
            .
            .
            </table>
```

jquery (to move row up and down)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".up,.down").click(function(){
          var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
          if ($(this).is(".up")) {
              row.insertBefore(row.prev());
          } else {
              row.insertAfter(row.next());
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: I've read your question three times and still don't understand what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry, just have a list of all checkbox values each time a row is moved. the checkbox valus is a pk, and I want to keep the order in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checks = new Array();
$(this).parents("table").find("input:checkbox").each(function() {
  checks.push($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

That will collect all the checkbox values into an array. You can put it before or after the re-ordering.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sr8Tk/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".up,.down").click(function(){
          var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
          if ($(this).is(".up")) {
              row.insertBefore(row.prev());
          } else {
              row.insertAfter(row.next());
          }
          var list = []; 
          $('input[name="layers"]').each(function(index, value) {
             list.push(value);

          });
          console.log(list);

      });
  });
```